# Why predefined interfaces exists in .NET

Tags: c#

I know concept of interfaces.. but one thing I couldn't understand that Why so many predefined interfaces are in .NET, like IComparable, IClonable, IFormattable, IDisposable? If just method is declared in these interfaces, then even we can define our own method and perom task. Then what is use of interfaces here?

Here my concept to ask this question is only one that Interface can declare only function signature, but can not define functionality... Then why predefined interfaces? Even in that we have to implement method that interface defines, then why that one not our own method?

Comment: becuase they're all used in out-of-the-box concrete `type`s in .net to abstract away implementation details ...

Comment: they exist so that you can create classes that implement them and have your classes pluggable into .Net framework

Comment: Interfaces are abstractions. The goal of the .NET framework is to provide useful abstractions, so you don't have to write your own.

Comment: _I know concept of interfaces.._ I doubt it

Comment: You probably should read on ["Duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which you suggest and related links that talk about comparison with other type systems which interfaces are part of. Note that C# supports duck typing to some extent with dynamics.

Answer (score 7):

Take `List<T>` for example, it has a `Sort` method. When you call `myList.Sort()`, the list will sort itself. But what if you want to control how it sorts? What goes first? What goes second? We need to help the sort method out and give it something to use for the sorting. That is where the other version of sort comes into play: `Sort(IComparer<T>)`

What should be given? Something that can take two items in our list and tell the sorting method which order they go in, so something like

```
int Compare(T a, T b);
```

This is exactly the method that is defined in `IComparer<T>`

We can totally write that method in any of our classes, but the problem is C# is a *strongly typed* language. We can't give `Sort` any old object -- even if it has that method on it -- it must be something that `Sort` is familiar with. Interfaces bridge that gap. Our class can implement `IComparer<T>`, and we can pass that to `Sort`, and since we know about `IComparer<T>` and so does `Sort`, everyone is happy and on the same page. The interface tells `Sort` to know the incoming object has `Compare` on it, and it can safely call it.